# convert the dict list to dataframe where we have 3 cols and making all keys into rows and a specific key into a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have input dict as below

sample=

```
    [
   {
      "SOURCE_VALUE":"1272323",
      "ASSOCIATED_ID_1":"1261523",
      "CHANGE_REQUEST_SUBMIT_ID":"11417",
      "ENTITIES_ID":"390258,390346",
      "PROPOSED_GROUP":"385920",
      "PROPOSED_UNIT":"403937",
      "PROPOSED_CENTER":"393306",
      "PROPOSED_DIVISION":"386774",
      "PROPOSED_ENTITIES":"390258,390346",
      "PROPOSED_COMPANY":"385895",
      "PROPOSED_1":"388316",
      "PROPOSED_2":"389046"
   },
   {
      "SOURCE_VALUE":"1272413",
      "ASSOCIATED_ID_1":"1261523",
      "CHANGE_REQUEST_SUBMIT_ID":"11417",
      "ENTITIES_ID":"390258,390346"
   },
   {
      "SOURCE_VALUE":"1272415",
      "ASSOCIATED_ID_1":"1261523",
      "CHANGE_REQUEST_SUBMIT_ID":"11417",
      "ENTITIES_ID":"390258,390346"
   }]
```

I want to have the output as

[image]

I want to have the souce_value from dict as a seperate column and rest all keys are as rows under "add keys" and targetvalue as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse each dict and add it to a list, finally convert it into a dataframe.

```
relationship = []
source_value = []
target_value = []

for d in sample:
    _source_value = d.pop("SOURCE_VALUE")
    keys, values = d.keys(), d.values()
    relationship += keys
    source_value += [_source_value]*len(keys)
    target_value += values

data = {
    'RELATIONSHIP': relationship,
    'SOURCE_VALUE': source_value,
    'TARGET_VALUE': target_value
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: To access a dictionary key and delete it, you can use the `pop` method. So you could write `_source_value = d.pop("SOURCE_VALUE")`.

Comment: Thnx.. Is there any inbult function we have in dataframe rather than parsing each dict??

Comment: You could make each dict to be a dataframe and then combine them, but that would add more complexity to a simple problem. This will be the best solution, consider marking it answered.